# Which set of diophantine equations could have the powers of two as result?

Tags: diophantine-equations, computability

[Matiyasevich's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich's_theorem) says, all the [computably enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) integer sets are [diophantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set). Thus, a set of diophantine equations exists, whose solution (in any of their variables) are this set.

Now consider the set of the integer powers of two. It is clearly recursively enumerable.

*Which diophantine equation could have this set as its solution?*

First I would say, that it is impossible - diophantine equations are polynomial, and my naive first spot is that they can't have this set of solutions in any of their variables. But this contradicts the MRDP theorem.

Comment: You might want to see this very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415556/how-to-express-the-powers-of-two-by-a-diophantine-equation.  Jones (cited in the answer) has done a lot of work on finding efficient Diophantine representations for interesting sets, but I'm not sure about powers of $2$ specifically.

Comment: Note that a Pell equation is polynomial and already generates exponentially-growing sequences.  So this can inform your intuition somewhat.  Of course, powers of $2$ will not arise in a Pell equation, but you might ask yourself what property is special about powers of $2$ that makes it feel impossible to arise from a polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is a power of $2$ iff

$$\forall a\,\forall b\,(2\cdot a+1)\cdot b=n\to a=0. $$
So let's start with something like 
$$ ((2a+1)b-n)^2$$
which is $\ge 0$ with equality iff $(2a+1)b=n$.
Now let's express that $a$ is a positive integer. By Lagrange's four-square-theorem,
this is equivalent to $\exists c\exists d\exists e\exists f\,a=1+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2$.
Thus from 
$$ P(n;a,b,c,d,e,f):=((2a+1)b-n)^2+(1+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2-a)^2$$
we see that the non-powers of $2$ are diophantine.

As $P$ is always non-negative, we arrive at the complement set by looking at
$$ Q(n;a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) := 1+g^2+h^2+i^2+j^2-P(n;a,b,c,d,e,f)$$

Comment: I didn't know this trick to get the complements. From a downvote to an upvote!

Comment: Could someone explain the complement trick to me?  It seems to me that $Q$ should yield all of $\mathbb N$ by just picking $a$ through $f$ at random to make $P(n;a,\ldots,f)$ positive.

Comment: I agree with @ErickWong - this doesn't seem right

Comment: @ErickWong Fixing your LaTeX (it rendered weirdly): "The polynomial $P$ is not identically $0$ (e.g. the coefficient of $f^4$ is 1). Thus there exists many choices of $a,\ldots,f$ that makes $P$ nonzero, hence positive. Thus $Q$ has an integer solution. But this means the Diophantine set defined by $Q$ consists of all $n$, not the powers of $2$."

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for the corrected repost!  I’ll delete my above comment in case it is causing rendering issues elsewhere, and you have restated it accurately.